# cancel join after sys.exit in multiprocessing

Tags: python, signals, multiprocessing

On OSX I create a tree of processes with multiprocessing.Process. When I send a signal to a parent process, the process enters a join state:

```
[INFO/MainProcess] process shutting down
[INFO/MainProcess] calling join() for process Process-1
```

I am already catching the signal with a signal handler and then calling sys.exit(1). Is there something I can call before sys.exit(1) that will prevent this process from waiting for its child?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this by using `os._exit(1)` instead of `sys.exit(1)`.

Comment: Keep in mind that using `os._exit()` means no cleanup at all is done prior to exiting your program. no `__del__()` getting called, buffers won't get flushed, etc.

Answer (score 3):

You can avoid this by setting the `daemon` property to `True` on your child processes. From the [`multiprocessing.Process`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.Process.daemon) docs (emphasis mine):

> daemon
>
> The process’s daemon flag, a Boolean value. This must be set before start() is called.
>
> The initial value is inherited from the creating process.
>
> **When a process exits, it attempts to terminate all of its daemonic child processes.**
>
> Note that a daemonic process is not allowed to create child processes. Otherwise a daemonic process would leave its children
>   orphaned if it gets terminated when its parent process exits.
>   Additionally, these are not Unix daemons or services, they are normal
>   processes that will be terminated (and not joined) if non-daemonic
>   processes have exited.

So if `p.daemon == True`, your parent process will just kill your child process, rather than `join` it. Note, though, that your daemonic processes cannot create their own children (as stated in the docs).

Comment: Nice to know, but I actually don't want to kill the child, just not join.

Comment: The multiprocessing module really isn't designed to create child processes that outlive the parent. It's meant to be used more like you'd use threads, where the child threads will always die with the parent program. If you want to create child processes that can outlive the parent, I'd recommend using the `subprocess` module instead.