# Python multiprocessing main function waits infinite even if child process error out

Tags: python, python-2.7, multiprocessing

I used python(2.7) module multiprocessing, to implement parallel processing in one of my scripts.

```
import sys
import multiprocessing

def myfun(file):
  try:
      <my logic>
  except Exception:
    sys.exit(-1)

my_file_list ['file1', 'file2', 'file3', 'file4', 'file5', 'file6', 'file7', 'file8', 'file9', 'file10', 'file11', ]
pool = multiprocessing.Pool(processes=3) 
pool.map(myfun, my_file_list )
```

Whenever my function myfun error out because of some file anomalies, my main function will go into a infinite wait! and I wi;; have to kill it. Can someone help me to fix my code/logic?

Comment: What kind of exception is raised in <your logic>? This might have to do with https://bugs.python.org/issue9400

Comment: Possible duplicate of [cancel join after sys.exit in multiprocessing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23934399/cancel-join-after-sys-exit-in-multiprocessing)

Comment: Getting error like this "(InvalidRange) when calling the GetObject operation: The requested range is not satisfiable"

Comment: You can also check this question. [Python Multiprocessing: Handling Child Errors in Parent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19924104/python-multiprocessing-handling-child-errors-in-parent)

Answer (score 0):

Don't call `sys.exit` unless you have a very good reason and know what you are doing: it's the pool's responsibility to manage the process. It looks like you don't need that try-except logic at all.